# Harry Potter fanfic where Harry's girlfriend is Sirius Black's daughter

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I read a fan fiction on fan fiction.com where Harry meets a girl I think at the start of the story, her last name was Silvers or something but her last name is in reality Black. Her first name is Kiara.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [The Angel](https://www.quotev.com/story/10504523/The-Angel) by [Word Addict](https://www.quotev.com/JolyneCortes). Over the course of the story Kiara's surname is revealed to be Black, and she is indeed Sirius Black's daughter.

> Kiara Silvers the girl whose birth bought happiness in the war. Whose laughter sounded like a voice of angel. Her kindness, bravery, selflessness, her wit beyond her age and her determination to fulfill any task. This girl was an angel for Hogwarts; a gift sent from heaven or that's what others thought.

I found an example of where Kiara is referred to as Sirius Black's daughter,

> Padfoot growled and barred [sic] his teeth towards Fudge for accusing his daughter and godson like this.
>
> <sub>[Chapter 57](https://www.quotev.com/story/10504523/The-Angel/59)</sub>

And where she is called her full name

> "I love you, Kiara Black" Harry whispered
>
> <sub>[Chapter 124](https://www.quotev.com/story/10504523/The-Angel/130)</sub>

Comment: is it a good story i dont remember much about it